# Wrong tag excerpt is shown for [uri] and [url] on finding tags

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

Find "uri" and "url" on https://stackoverflow.com/tags:

[image: example]

Actually, "a Uniform Resouce Identifier (URI) that ..." is current tag excerpt for [uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uri) not [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url).

rev 2016.12.16.4351 / Windows 10 / Chrome 57

Comment: Wow, this would be a serious problem if anyone ever actually read the tag excerpts :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not showing incorrect excerpts; it just shortens the beginning of them in a slightly confusing way.

---

The excerpt displayed on the search page for [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url) is:

> a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) that specifies where an identified resource is available and the mechanism for retrieving it.

The excerpt for [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url) is (emphasis mine):

> A Uniform Resource Locator (URL) is **a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) that specifies where an identified resource is available and the mechanism for retrieving it.**

---

The excerpt displayed on the search page for [uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uri) is:

> a string of characters used to identify a name or resource.

The excerpt for [uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uri) is (again, emphasis mine):

> A Uniform Resource Identifier (or URI) is **a string of characters used to identify a name or resource.**